# Auto-layout problem (?) with custom tableView cells | Swift

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, tableview, custom-cell

Hi guys :) I'm kinda having a problem with auto-layout my custom cells, im having 5 custom cells which all are loaded but the thing is they override each other no matter what I do, Im trying to find the problem of it but I dont seem to find it :\ would love to get a hand with that please.
Btw : Im not using any storyboards.

Here's my tableView's code:

```
import UIKit
import PanModal


class FilterTableViewController: UITableViewController, PanModalPresentable {
    var panScrollable: UIScrollView? {
        return tableView
    }
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupTableView()
//        registerTableViewCells()
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
//        tableView.frame = view.bounds
    }
    
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
    
    
    
    // MARK: - View Configurations
    
    func setupTableView() {
        
        
        tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

        
        tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
        tableView.isScrollEnabled = false // We don't want it to scroll
        tableView.allowsSelection = false

        
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.rowHeight = 80
        
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)

    }
    
    private func registerTableViewCells() {
        let textFieldCell = UINib(nibName: "byActivityCell",
                                  bundle: nil)
        self.tableView.register(textFieldCell,
                                forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    
    
    
    // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            let byActivityCell = UINib(nibName: "byActivityCell",bundle: nil)
            self.tableView.register(byActivityCell,forCellReuseIdentifier: "byActivityCell")
            return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "byActivityCell", for: indexPath) as! byActivityCell
            
        case 1:
            let byTypeCell = UINib(nibName: "ByType",bundle: nil)
            self.tableView.register(byTypeCell,forCellReuseIdentifier: "byTypeCell")
            return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "byTypeCell", for: indexPath) as! ByType
            
        case 2:
            let byHashtagsCell = UINib(nibName: "ByHashtags",bundle: nil)
            self.tableView.register(byHashtagsCell,forCellReuseIdentifier: "byHashtagsCell")
            return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "byHashtagsCell", for: indexPath) as! ByHashtags
            
        case 3:
            let byDatesCell = UINib(nibName: "DatesCell",bundle: nil)
            self.tableView.register(byDatesCell,forCellReuseIdentifier: "byDatesCell")
            return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "byDatesCell", for: indexPath) as! DatesCell
            
            
        case 4:
            let byAlbumCell = UINib(nibName: "AlbumCell",bundle: nil)
            self.tableView.register(byAlbumCell,forCellReuseIdentifier: "byAlbumCell")
            return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "byAlbumCell", for: indexPath) as! AlbumCell
            
        default:
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    // MARK: - footer Methods:
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return getfooterView()
    }

    func getfooterView() -> UIView
    {
        let Header = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Double(self.tableView.frame.size.width), height: 45))
        Header.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "#2AF8AC")

        let button = UIButton()
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Header.frame.size.width-10, height: Header.frame.size.height)
        
        
        
        button.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        button.layer.masksToBounds = true

        button.setTitle("Apply Filters", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)

        //       button.addTarget(self, action: nil, for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)

        Header.addSubview(button)
        Header.bringSubviewToFront(button)
        return Header
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 45
    }

    
    
}
```

Here's how it looks like: [Link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpBfs.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove this line:

   tableView.rowHeight = 80
2. Follow this guideline:
   *The trick to get Auto Layout working on a UITableViewCell is to ensure that you have constraints to pin each subview on all sides — that is, each subview should have leading, top, trailing and bottom constraints. Then, the intrinsic height of the subviews will be used to dictate the height of each cell.*

(quoted from https://www.raywenderlich.com/8549-self-sizing-table-view-cells)

Comment: OK. I have edited my answer and added the 2nd section

Comment: awesome tutorial bro :) will read that one maybe they got the answer for me.